# pivoted data frame with catagorical column fails to print

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using a Pandas DataFrame to manage some results data. To achieve ‘slice and dice’ on my data frame I use the ‘pivot_table’ function. In addition to this, to get a custom ordering of columns I convert one of my columns to be a ‘categorical’ column.
I’m finding that when I try and print the data frame it gives the following error:

AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'flags'

If I change my code so that the column is not ‘categorical’ then it works. But then my pivoted result has the default (alphabetical) column order.

Here is a cut down version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Build data frame
data=[
    (1, 'ABC', '3M', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '1Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '2Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '3Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '5Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '7Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '10Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '15Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '20Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '25Y', 0.1), 
    (1, 'ABC', '30Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '3M', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '1Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '2Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '3Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '5Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '7Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '10Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '15Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '20Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '25Y', 0.1), 
    (2, 'ABC', '30Y', 0.1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=('Ord', 'Name', 'label', 'Value'))

# Obtain a custom sorted list of lables
label_sort_order = {'3M': 1, '1Y': 2, '2Y': 3, '3Y': 4, '5Y': 5, '7Y': 6, '10Y': 7, '15Y': 8, '20Y': 9, '25Y': 10, '30Y': 11}
labels = label_sort_order.keys()
labels = sorted(labels, key=lambda label: label_sort_order[label])

# Convert label column to 'Categorical' so when pivoted it will respect the custom column ordering
df['label'] = pd.Categorical(df['label'], labels)
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name'], columns=['Ord', 'label'])

print(df_pivot) # Thows exception
```

I’m using python 3.4.3 and have pandas 0.16.2 installed.

Can anyone explain why this exception occurs and how to avoid it? Alternatively, perhaps there’s a better way, all I want to do is control the column order of my pivoted data frame.

Comment: With pandas 0.17.1 your code works flawlessly. Can you try updating to the latest version?

Comment: It works for me with python 2.7 and pandas 0.17.1, it might be a bug in your version of pandas. Are you able to update to the latest version? As a workaround you could keep the labels as strings or convert them to `Period`.

Comment: I updated to pandas 0.17.1 and the problem goes away. I'm happy with that for now. Thanks very much for the tip.

Comment: Great, now you can try `reindex` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the labels at any level in a multiindex with the `reindex` function:

First I reuse your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=('Ord', 'Name', 'label', 'Value'))
label_sort_order = {'3M': 1, '1Y': 2, '2Y': 3, '3Y': 4, '5Y': 5, '7Y': 6, '10Y': 7, '15Y': 8, '20Y': 9, '25Y': 10, '30Y': 11}
labels = label_sort_order.keys()
labels = sorted(labels, key=lambda label: label_sort_order[label])
```

Then I transpose in order to use the `reindex` function:

```
df_pivot.transpose().reindex(labels, level='label')
```

**Update**: `reindex` is new in pandas 0.17. You should definitely consider updating.

Comment: I just checked: `reindex` is new in pandas 0.17. It's nicer than using a categorical column though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ordered Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order) for creating column `label`:

```
# Obtain a custom sorted list of lables
label_sort_order = {'3M': 1, '1Y': 2, '2Y': 3, '3Y': 4, '5Y': 5, '7Y': 6, '10Y': 7, '15Y': 8, '20Y': 9, '25Y': 10, '30Y': 11}
print label_sort_order
{'3Y': 4, '5Y': 5, '1Y': 2, '2Y': 3, '3M': 1, '30Y': 11, '15Y': 8, '25Y': 10, '20Y': 9, '10Y': 7, '7Y': 6}

#swap keys and values in dictionary label_sort_order
swap_dict = dict((v,k) for k,v in label_sort_order.items())
print swap_dict
{1: '3M', 2: '1Y', 3: '2Y', 4: '3Y', 5: '5Y', 6: '7Y', 7: '10Y', 8: '15Y', 9: '20Y', 10: '25Y', 11: '30Y'}

#create new Series - is sorted by keys converted to index
s = pd.Series(swap_dict)
print s
1      3M
2      1Y
3      2Y
4      3Y
5      5Y
6      7Y
7     10Y
8     15Y
9     20Y
10    25Y
11    30Y
dtype: object

#get sorted values of Series s
print s.values
['3M' '1Y' '2Y' '3Y' '5Y' '7Y' '10Y' '15Y' '20Y' '25Y' '30Y']
#add parameter ordered=True
print pd.Categorical(df['label'], categories=s.values, ordered=True)
[3M, 1Y, 2Y, 3Y, 5Y, ..., 10Y, 15Y, 20Y, 25Y, 30Y]
Length: 22
Categories (11, object): [3M < 1Y < 2Y < 3Y ... 15Y < 20Y < 25Y < 30Y]
```

```
df['label'] = pd.Categorical(df['label'], categories=s.values, ordered=True)

print pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name'], columns=['Ord', 'label'])
      Value                                              ...                  \
Ord       1                                              ...     2             
label    3M   1Y   2Y   3Y   5Y   7Y  10Y  15Y  20Y  25Y ...    1Y   2Y   3Y   
Name                                                     ...                   
ABC     0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ...   0.1  0.1  0.1   


Ord                                       
label   5Y   7Y  10Y  15Y  20Y  25Y  30Y  
Name                                      
ABC    0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  

[1 rows x 22 columns]
```